# Join column in where clause using split

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My stored procedure accepts a parameter with values like

```
Declare @Temp VarChar(Max)
Set @Temp = 'S1CW3733|1050105000224,S1CW4923|1050105000009'
```

Where values is like

```
Column1|Column2,Column1|Column2,Column1|Column2,
```

I want to apply same in SQL query like

```
Select * 
From ATMStatus 
Where ATM + '|' + Fault IN (@Temp)
```

How can I achieve this?

Database is SQL Server 2008

Comment: Duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/sql-server-2008-how-to-split-a-comma-seperated-value-to-columns , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215267/how-to-split-the-comma-separated-string-with-out-using-loop-in-stored-procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small tables, you can use the table scanning solution, assuming ATM and Fault can never contain comma (`,`) or pipe (`|`):

```
Select *
  From ATMStatus
 Where ',' + @Temp + ',' LIKE '%,' + ATM + '|' + Fault + ',%';
```

For large tables, you'll need to employ a splitting function to turn the variable into a multi-row, 2 column table, which would then be used something like:

```
Select a.*
  From ATMStatus a
  join dbo.SplitVarTo2ColumnTable(@Temp) b
       on b.Column1 = a.ATM and b.Column2 = a.Fault;
```